# Matlab AWGN noise expression

Tags: matlab

I am trying to add awgn noise to a signal. the signal is s and the received signal is y obtained through:

```
    y = s+ n;
```

where I want n to be the additive white Gaussian noise. Can some one please tell me the exact mathematical expression for AWGN. I don't want to use the in-built AWGN function of matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can some one please tell me the exact mathematical expression for AWGN.

[`randn`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/randn.html).

> I don't want to use the in-built AWGN function of matlab.

Why not?

Comment: i want to simulate without dependence on built-in functions. It helps build a good understanding of stuff.

Comment: and is it just randn this means y = s + randn would be equivalent to passing the signal through an AWGN channel?

Comment: @user899714: `randn` generates unit-variance Gaussian numbers, which is exactly what AWGN with a power of 1 is.

Answer (score 0):

AWGN basically says that noise is added to a channel, and that noise is Normally distributed.

The `n` you are looking for is a random variable that is normally distributed. There is no mathematical expression that gives you `n` (Although there is a [mathematical expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) that tells you how frequently different `n` values should occur, that expression is the PDF or Probability Distribution Function)

What `randn` does in Matlab is generate a random number from a Normal distribution.

If you really want to understand what's going on you should look into how "random" numbers are generated in computers with different distributions, but that's probably deeper than you need to go.

I recommend just using the `randn` function in Matlab and reading the documentation to see how you can change the mean and standard deviation of the distribution.

Comment: Thanks the detail was helpful!